# Clearing a form field after using append to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using an ajax function to append a comment to a a list of existing comments.  I have the append to working, but after I append the comment is still in the text field.  I am trying to figure out how to clear the text field after the append to.  Any pointers on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated.

```
$('.new_question_comment').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $form = $(event.currentTarget);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    data: $form.serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
    $form.siblings().first().append("<h6>"+ "-" + data.body + "</h6><br>")
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: in success handler clear the input elements `$form.find(':input').val('')` - or  use a more specific selector to target the comment input element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `success` callback function add the following after you append the data:

```
$form.each (function() { this.reset(); });
```

This will reset the form values back to their default.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/wCFNu/)

You could also use the native JavaScript form reset function:

```
$form[0].reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the specific text field has an ID, say "text", clear it directly:

```
document.getElementById('text').value='';
```

You can clear the entire form too:

```
document.getElementById('form').reset();
```